# why persian data is not shown correctly instead of using utf8 in both inserting and selecting data?(words are shown correctly in phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

i am developing an application which reads data from mysql database on server and shows them to user so android part is operating properly but when i request data in a php page from mysql database using php result is :

> \u00d9\u2026\u00d8\u00ad\u00d9\u2026\u00d8\u00af

connection to database is :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_select_db("araspcoc_usersdb",$con);
```

this is the script which recives the data :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $r",$con);
$response = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$temp['name'] = $row['name'];
$temp['email'] = $row['email'];
$temp['phone'] = $row['phone'];
$temp['date'] = $row['date'];
$response["requests"]=array();
array_push($response["requests"],$temp);
}
$response["t"]=1;
echo json_encode($response);
}else{
echo "no result";
}
```

and i have to remind that befor i use utf 8 encoding to recive data data used to be like this ?????

Comment: This is valid unicode encoded as json, just what your code should do.

Comment: should i use pdo or mysqli?

Comment: i have already sat collations as utf8 general ci but nothing changed